# Which Mozilla Firebug version works best for firebug

Tags: firefox-addon, firebug, mozilla

I have installed Mozilla firebox on my system but still, firebug doesn't work. Can anyone help which version of Mozilla Firefox should I install use firebug addon.

[image]

Comment: pre Quantum.... Read https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/

Comment: Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/). It is recommended to use the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the latest version of Firebug is supported in Firefox version 30.0. The searched and getting a result like this.
[image]

The latest version of Firebug is 2.0.19 and works with Firefox 30.0
Actually it's sad to say that Firebug Support has been stopped by Firefox due to the launch of new version of Firefox browser `Firefox Quantum`, but the good news is that all the capabilities of Firebug are now present in current `Firefox Developer Tools.`